# Logstash stats API is showing wrong events values

Tags: elasticsearch, logstash

I'm using logstash from a docker image, I'm consulting the stats API to show the logs processed by a pipeline to the user, but when I send 200 logs every 0.01 seconds the event information is showing wrong values. If I restart the pipeline and send a few logs every 1 or two seconds, the event information shows the right values

Node information:

```
"host": "19b4437c6bd2",
    "version": "7.17.4",
    "http_address": "0.0.0.0:9600",
    "id": "90a19e53-5c93-4268-94e6-641e763e6017",
    "name": "19b4437c6bd2",
    "ephemeral_id": "b409fac0-0a62-4a8c-a5e0-225128fbfabd",
    "status": "green",
    "snapshot": false,
    "pipeline": {
        "workers": 8,
        "batch_size": 125,
        "batch_delay": 50
    }
```

Events information of the pipeline:

```
"syslog": {
            "events": {
                "duration_in_millis": 41578,
                "out": 13935,
                "filtered": 144,
                "queue_push_duration_in_millis": 0,
                "in": 144
            }
```

During my tests, I realised that out is showing the right values of the logs indexed in elastic but not in and filtered values. Does anyone have an idea if there is a bug, or can we configure something in logstash to avoid that behaviour?

Comment: Which Logstash version are you using?

Comment: Is in the node information 7.17.4